# Scraping website with R: XML content does not seem to be XML

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, screen-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape the table from a website (https://www.freedraftguide.com/fantasy-football/rankings/quarterbacks) and I've tried several approaches without success.  When I run the code below, I get the following error: `XML content does not seem to be XML`

```
library("XML")
library("RCurl")

readHTMLTable("https://www.freedraftguide.com/fantasy-football/rankings/quarterbacks")
```

None of the approaches below using `RCurl` worked either:

```
rts.url <- getURL("https://www.freedraftguide.com/fantasy-football/rankings/quarterbacks")
xmlParse(rts.url)
xmlInternalTreeParse(rts.url)
readHTMLTable(rts.url)
```

No success with `httr`:

```
library("httr")
GET("https://www.freedraftguide.com/fantasy-football/rankings/quarterbacks")
```

No success with `rvest`:

```
library("rvest")
read_html("https://www.freedraftguide.com/fantasy-football/rankings/quarterbacks")
```

I'm less familiar with RSelenium, but here's my attempt based on the example in the documentation:

```
library("RSelenium")

startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver$new()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.freedraftguide.com/fantasy-football/rankings/quarterbacks")

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
 Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
 class: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException
```

Comment: The data is being loaded with jQuery, so you need to load the page with something that can run it, like RSelenium.

Comment: Just added an attempt with RSelenium (less familiar with it, but still getting an error based on the example in the documentation). Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I managed to get an xml with rvest::html even though it gives a warning stating that rvest::html is deprecated... I didn't get an error with xml2::read_html either though...

Comment: I don't get an error with rvest or xml2, but I don't get the table on the page, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tricky tables such as this one, I often find that finding xpath from Firebug or Developer Tools is often the most helpful option.

```
library("RSelenium")

startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver$new()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.freedraftguide.com/fantasy-football/rankings/quarterbacks")
player_table <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody')

print(player_table$getElementText())

players <- strsplit(player_table$getElementText()[[1]], "\n")

final <- c()
for(x in players[[1]]){
  temp <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
  final <- rbind(final, temp)
}

final <- data.frame(final)

R> print(head(final))
  X1      X2             X3  X4 X5 X6   X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12
1 1.   Aaron        Rodgers GNB  4 39 4391  0  2 311  54  27
2 2.     Cam         Newton CAR  7 33 3982  0  9 651 130  27
3 3.  Andrew           Luck IND 10 36 4769  0  2 283  60  26
4 4.    Drew          Brees NOR  5 33 4925  0  1  41  26  22
5 5.     Ben Roethlisberger PIT  8 35 4916  0  0  43  31  20
6 6. Russell         Wilson SEA  5 34 4063  0  4 592 109  20
```

I realize that the `for` loop is less than ideal but sometimes for scraping webpages such as this it can be the best option.